# How do you layout buttons in a table format?

Tags: c#, wpf

How would you approach making a "table" filled with buttons?

```
Ex. (b=button control)

b b b b b

b b b b b

b b b b b

b b b b b
```

I understand how to generally use Dock and Stack Panels.  Would I have to make a nested group of stack panels where I make 5 vertical stack panels and then place them in a horizontal stack panel? or is there an easier way?

Comment: See [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<UniformGrid Rows="5" Columns="5">
   <!-- your buttons -->
</UniformGrid>
```

You can learn about the `UniformGrid` at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx).

Constraining the `Rows` is optional, if you may have more than exactly 25 buttons.

If you do not necessarily want all the cells of the grid to have equal size, then you can lay out a standard `Grid`. The drawback to that is that declaring the `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions` properties is verbose.

Comment: Although this is similar to the first answer it has contributed to furthering my understanding.  I want all my cells to be the same size but I would like my buttons to be rectangular (spanning further across the row than down the column). Will this be an issue?

Comment: @muffinMan No, that should not be a problem at all. If you want something a bit clearer than the MSDN information, check out this post: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFUniformGrid.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you dont mind the buttons being evenly spaced you could use

```
<UniformGrid Columns="5">
    <Button />
    ...
    <Button />
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: @LPL Thank you both for your quick responses.  This is exactly what I am looking for as I am starting one of my first large projects and would like to keep the formatting as simple as possible.